# Concatenate PySpark Dataframe Column Names by Value and Sum

Tags: pyspark

I have an example dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, "something"),
    (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, "something"),
    (3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, "something"),
    (4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, "something"),
    (5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, "something"),
    (6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "something")
   ], ["int" * 6, "string"]) \
  .toDF("id", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "extra_column")
df.show()

+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+
| id|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|extra_column|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+
|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|  1|   something|
|  2|  0|  1|  1|  1|  0|   something|
|  3|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|   something|
|  4|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|   something|
|  5|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|   something|
|  6|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|   something|
```

I want to concatenate across the columns per row and produce a key where the column `= 1`. I don't need to show this result but this is the intermediate step I need to solve:

```
df_row_concat = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, "something", "bcde"),
    (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, "something", "bcd"),
    (3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, "something", "a"),
    (4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, "something", "b"),
    (5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, "something", "a"),
    (6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "something", "")
   ], ["int" * 6, "string" * 2]) \
  .toDF("id", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "extra_column", "key")
df_row_concat.show()

+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+----+
| id|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|extra_column| key|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+----+
|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|  1|   something|bcde|
|  2|  0|  1|  1|  1|  0|   something| bcd|
|  3|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|   something|   a|
|  4|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|   something|   b|
|  5|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|   something|   a|
|  6|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|   something|    |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+----+
```

This last part I can get on my own, but to complete the example, I want to sum the key values and output:

```
+----+-----+
| key|value|
+----+-----+
|   a|    2|
|   b|    1|
| bcd|    1|
|bcde|    1|
+----+-----+
```

My actual dataset is much longer and wider. I could hard-code every combination but there must be a more efficient way to loop over the list of columns to consider (e.g. `column_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`). Maybe not necessary, but I included the `extra_column` because there are additional columns in my dataset which won't be considered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with writing a for loop here

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

temp = (df.withColumn('key', F.concat(*[F.when(F.col(c) == 1, c).otherwise('') for c in cols])))

+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+----+
| id|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|extra_column| key|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+----+
|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|  1|   something|bcde|
|  2|  0|  1|  1|  1|  0|   something| bcd|
|  3|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|   something|   a|
|  4|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|   something|   b|
|  5|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|   something|   a|
|  6|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|   something|    |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+----+

(temp
    .groupBy('key')
    .agg(F.count('*').alias('value'))
    .where(F.col('key') != '')
    .show()
)

+----+-----+
| key|value|
+----+-----+
|bcde|    1|
|   b|    1|
|   a|    2|
| bcd|    1|
+----+-----+
```